# How can I re-style the search text color?

Tags: react-select

I am using the react-select v2 component and am having difficulty restyling the input text for the search portion of the component.

Here is the component itself:

`<AsyncSelect
        value={this.props.value}
        onChange={this.props.onChange}
        isSearchable
        options={
          this.state.options
        }
        onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
        styles={styleSheet}
      />`

Here is the stylesheet:

`const styleSheet = {
      input: (base, state) => ({
        ...base,
        color: "red"
      }),
    };`

This seems to have no effect on the text color, though I'm unsure as to why.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit:
I can see in components/Input.js that there is no support for "color":

`const inputStyle = isHidden => ({
  background: 0,
  border: 0,
  fontSize: 'inherit',
  opacity: isHidden ? 0 : 1,
  outline: 0,
  padding: 0,
});`

In which case would this need to be a feature request, or is there some alternate way of applying this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const styleSheet = {
  input: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    '[type="text"]': {
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica, sans-serif !important',
      fontSize: 13,
      fontWeight: 900,
      color: 'green'
    }
  })
};
```

And then later in your render method:

```
<Select styles={styleSheet} />
```

Comment: What worked for me is to remove the '[type="text"]' encapsulation and put color prop on next line below base param spread.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the CSS rule `!important` because without that the code doesn't work for me.

```
const customStyles = {
  input: (styles) => ({
    ...styles,
    '[type="text"]': {
      color: 'white !important'
    }
  })
};
```